# Search in more than one table - give result as one column

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Hey stackoverflow - This is my first question here.

I have 2 tables in my mySQLdb.

```
[tab_artist]
|id|artist|count  

[tab_songtitle]
|id|songtitle|artistId
```

Im trying to select from both tab_artist.artist and tab_songtitle.songtitle as suggest where searchclause = m

I have tried this

```
SELECT artist, songtitle AS suggest 
FROM tab_artist, tab_songtitle 
WHERE artist LIKE('m%') OR songtitle LIKE('m%')
```

But this gives me 2 columns, artist and suggest

if the search is met i need artist to give me e.g. metallica.. but only once - but in songtitles i need all titles starting with met.

Hope this makes sence to the right expert :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `union` should do it:

```
select artist    AS suggest from tab_artist    WHERE artist    LIKE 'm%'
union all
select songtitle AS suggest from tab_songtitle WHERE songtitle LIKE 'm%'
```

For this case, I would use `union all` so you won't get duplicates removed, but you may want this if, for example, Metallica has a self-titled album and you only want the word to appear once. In that case, `union` would be more appropriate.

Comment: That's just excactly what I want :) thx alot and thx for your interrest in my question to all three of you :)

Comment: I get your point. But how do i make sure that if e.g. metallica has a titletrack called metallica that i only the the word once?

Comment: Use union instead of union all - it will remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You need a join:

```
Select artist, songtitle from tab_artist inner join tab_songtitle on tab_songtitle.artistID = tab_artist.ID where artist LIKe ('m%') OR songtitle like ('m%')
```

Comment: I did not read the one column part, please disregard my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use SQL UNION

```
select id, artist, count FROM table1
UNION
select id, title, artistid from table2
```

It basically concats the two result sets vertically.  There are some restrictions and modifications, but generally thats all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION ALL` to concatenate the results from the artist and song tables.

```
SELECT 'Artist' AS type, id, artist AS suggest
FROM tab_artist
WHERE artist LIKE 'm%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Song', id, songtitle
FROM tab_songtitle
WHERE songtitle LIKE 'm%'
```

Don't use `UNION` as some are suggesting as that will do a completely unnecessary (and expensive) `DISTINCT` on the query results.

Comment: This is what i have now: 
select distinct(artist) AS suggest from tab_artist WHERE artist LIKE('ma%')
union all
select distinct(songtitle) AS suggest from tab_songtitle WHERE songtitle LIKE('ma%')

Would that give me metallica only once, even if theres an artist and a songtitle named metallica ?